# Oculus Rift SDK 2 changing the rotational gain

Tags: redirect, audio, oculus

We are conducting an experiment in which the user of the HMD has to experience multiple rotational gains. With this I mean that we would like to change te relative rotation of a users head to the rotational gain in the virtual world.
For example, a rotational gain of 2 would mean that when I change the yaw of my head in real life with 45 degrees, then I would like that the virtual world changes its yaw with 90 degrees.

We have our hands on the Oculus Rift Development Kit 2 and would like to apply this ability to change this parameter in the 'World Demo' example, that comes with the SDK2 software (available at: https://developer.oculusvr.com/).

I have tried to find this part of the code myself. However, I'm not an experienced program and this is my first time working with the Oculus Rift.

Comment: Are you trying to change the rotation on all axes, or just yaw?

Comment: Just the yaw is sufficient, but all axes is also okay.

Answer (score 0):

Oculus have now officially added integration with the free version of Unity, which if you're an inexperienced programmer, I highly recommend using instead of the C++ SDK. If you look at the Unity 'Tuscany' demo that comes with the Unity integration tools, you'll find scripts such as OVRPlayerController.cs, OVRCameraRig.cs and the OVRTracker.cs and more which you'll need to modify in order to achieve what you're looking for. I suggest looking at changing the rotation in the UpdateMovement() method in OVRPlayerController.cs to start with.